# Twilio IP Messaging fails after 1 hr

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have Using Twilio IP messaging from IOS and Android. It is found after one hr session timeouts and not possible to send message to Twilio, Initializing every time will take 10 sec delay. I found a ttl option while creating token, But it returns token back but channel creation fails. Any good solution for it?

```
var twilioAccessTokenExpiryTime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
var token = new AccessToken(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET,
  { ttl: twilioAccessTokenExpiryTime }
);
```

Comment: You should be able to set the ttl to be up to 24 hours. What is the code you've been using for that so far?

Comment: var twilioAccessTokenExpiryTime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
var token = new AccessToken(
                          process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
                          process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
                          process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET, {
                             ttl: twilioAccessTokenExpiryTime
                          }
                      );

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to edit your question with both the code that you've commented with (it's easier to read that way) and the error message you receive when channel creation fails.